# Error setting image format: Can not process empty Imagick object

Tags: php, imagick

I am getting an error when I am converting the HEIC format to pdf.

the code breaks on the line

```
$imagick->setImageFormat('pdf');
```

This line gives an error

> Error setting image format: Can not process empty Imagick object.

Your answer will be appreciated.

```
if ($doc['file_type'] == 'application/octet-stream') {
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("Converting HEIC document : " . print_r($doc, true));
    $document_name = $doc['document_revision_id'];
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("PDF saved at: 1");
    $directory = "upload/";
    $img_path = $directory .$document_name;
    $pdfPath = $directory .$document_name;
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("PDF saved at: " .$img_path);
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("PDF saved at: 2");
    // Load the HEIC image using Imagick
    $imagick = new \Imagick();
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("PDF saved at: 3");
    
    $imagick->readImage('heif:', $img_path);
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("PDF saved at: 4");
    // Convert the HEIC image to PDF
    try {
        $imagick->setImageFormat('pdf');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("Error setting image format: " . $error_message);
        return false; // or handle the error as needed
    }
    // $imagick->setImageFormat('pdf');
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("PDF saved at: 5");
    // $pdfPath = "path/to/save/converted/pdf.pdf";
    $imagick->writeImages($pdfPath, true);
    
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("PDF saved at: " . $pdfPath);

    //Changing file name + file extension
    $document_revision_bean = BeanFactory::getBean('DocumentRevisions', $doc['document_revision_id']);
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("Old File Ext : " . $document_revision_bean->file_ext);
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("Old File Name : " . $document_revision_bean->filename);
    $file_name_arr = explode(".", $document_revision_bean->filename);
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("File ext From Name: " . end($file_name_arr));

    $newName = $this->lastReplace(end($file_name_arr), "pdf", $document_revision_bean->filename);
    $GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("New File Name : " . $newName);
    $document_revision_bean->filename = $newName;
    $document_revision_bean->file_ext = 'pdf';
    $document_revision_bean->save();
}
```